# zend translate for view & controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I initialize translation in controller.

```
public function init(){
  $this->translate  = new Zend_Translate('csv', '../application/configs/translate.tr', 'tr');
```

But I want to use translate in view. 
Should I initialize as the same way as controller? 
How can I implement what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just initialize the translation in `application.ini`. The application resource will we available everywhere.

Example:

```
resources.translate.registry_key = "Zend_Translate"
resources.translate.adapter = "gettext"
resources.translate.options.logUntranslated = false
resources.translate.options.scan = "directory"
resources.translate.options.disableNotices = 1
;resources.translate.options.logfile = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/log/application.log"
resources.translate.data = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/languages"
resources.translate.locale = "fr" ; default language
```

You may also get `Zend_Translate` instance from the registry.

Comment: can you pass application.ini strings?